# Installing Papyros QML Material plugin in Qt Linux

Tags: qt, plugins, qml, material-design, qt-quick

I'm trying to install qml-material plugin from papyros in my Qt. I have completed these steps so far

1. Cloned qml-material repo from [here](https://github.com/papyros/qml-material)
2. opened "qml-material.pro" file in repository's root directory in Qt Creator
3. Built the project in release. It created "libmaterial.so" and similar files in the build directory.
4. In the build directory executed "make install"

After this step I don't know what to do. Please correct me if I have done something wrong and guide me what do I do next in order to use this plugin in a project.